# Why does my Electron app quit when closing a Renderer window?

Tags: electron

I'm testing on Windows. 
The app sets up a Tray menu on 'ready', with an 'About' label. When clicked, it shows a BrowserWindow:

```
 var aboutBox = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 460, height: 176, useContentSize: true,
        icon: iconImg,
        maximizable: false, fullscreenable: false, resizable: false, minimizable: false
    });
```

and then, when the user clicks on OK, closing it with:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
```

causes the app to exit.

Why?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your main.js you could have this code:

```
// Quit when all windows are closed.

  app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar  
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

So because you close the unique windows this event it's emitted and app is closed.

**EDIT**
This behavior is also default in Electron, so to avoid closing app closing the main window add this line:

```
app.on('window-all-closed', e => e.preventDefault() )
```

Comment: Well, I don't have that in my main.js. Is that like a built-in default in Electron?