# Creating a window and hiding it when close button is clicked

Tags: node.js, electron

I have been trying to create a tray app that has two options, first one creates a browser window and the second one closes the tray process.
After writing the basic structure I tested it out, the tray application quit when I closed the main browser window. Upon digging up the internet, I found [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/object-has-been-destroyed-when-open-secondary-child-window/30880/4?u=spyshow).

Things start to get weird after this part. If I start my electron app with visual studio, I can open/show and hide the app for 4-6 times then it freezes. If I start the app with `npm start`, I can only open and hide it for two times, then it completely freezes.
I wondered if it was a problem with ubuntu so I booted up a Windows VM and installed the electron module for windows as a dependency on that project.
If use the same project on windows, I can create/show and hide the app 14-16 times even if I start it with `npm start`, after that, the tray icon just disappears.
Here's my code

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, Tray, ipcMain} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;
let windowshown = false;
let eventcount = 0;

app.on('ready', createWindow)

function createWindow () {
      let tray = null
      tray = new Tray('path/to/image.jpg')
      const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        { label: 'Open blank window', click:() => {
          console.log("called createwin");
          createwin();
                                                  }
        },
      {label: 'Try to quit', click: (item, window, event) => {
        if (windowshown == true){
          mainWindow.removeAllListeners('close');
          mainWindow = null
      }
        app.quit();
      }},
    ])
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
    }


function createwin(){
    if (windowshown == false) {
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1000,
            height: 800,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        })
        mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("Window has been hidden");
          mainWindow.hide();
          //return 0;
      });
        console.log("Window has been created")
        windowshown = true;
        mainWindow.loadFile('nothing.html');

    }
    else {
        mainWindow.show();
        eventcount++;
        console.log("Window has been shown " + eventcount + " time(s)");
    }
  }
```

Here's the output on ubuntu

```
called createwin
Window has been shown 1 time(s)
Window has been hidden
.
.
.
called createwin
Window has been shown 10 time(s)
Window has been hidden
(tray app becomes unresponsive so I stop the debugger)
Window has been hidden
```

Windows produces a similar result but I can open/close the app more than 16 times.
While writing this, stackoverflow suggested me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599404/5201842) but it's solution did not help either. 
Is there a proper way to do it?
[(I also asked a similar question here if that helps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443627/mainwindow-onclose-gets-called-more-than-one-time-when-i-hide-mainwindow)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't correspond to the output. Did you include the entire [mcve]? The `Window has been hidden` message is not in your code. How do you expect to hide the window? Closing the window shuts down the app, you'll need to override that. Also, there is a bug: `if (windowshown = true){` should be `==`, otherwise you set the variable at this point!

Comment: I don't know how that specific line got deleted but, here it is, this is the code I used on both systems.
Also thanks for the heads up, I'll fix that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which problem you're exactly having.

Besides the now-corrected `if (windowshown = true){` that should read `==`, the tray icon vanishes after some time.

This is likely caused by the fact that you declare the variable within the ready handler. It is therefore removed by garbage collection after some time.

If you move the declaration in the main part (same level as `mainWindow`), the tray will stick around.

Comment: Yup, garbage collector was the case.